# How to two-way data bind in nested array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Say you have a list of tasks which in turn has a list of subtasks and you want the subtasks to be changable - How come that angular doesn't properly two-way bind the data for the subtask?

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
  Task value: <input [(ngModel)]="task.value">
  <br>
  <div *ngFor="let subtask of task.subtasks">
    Subtask: <input [(ngModel)]="subtask">
    </div>
</div>

{{ tasks | json }}
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  tasks = [{
    value: 'Task 1',
    subtasks: ['Hello']
  }]  
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agrzfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with ngFor Each input has to have a **`unique name`** . To solve it,

use **`task.subtasks[index]`** instead of item with ngModel

Also you need to use trackByIndex inorder to avoid the slowness as it  re-creates the DOM every time you change a string in your array

```
<div *ngFor="let subtask of task.subtasks;let index = index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    Subtask: <input [(ngModel)]="task.subtasks[index]">
</div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyrhpg?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to access index of sublist like on this code snippet

add index counter on list and access via tas.sublist[i]

```
   <div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
      Task value: <input [(ngModel)]="task.value">
    <br>
    <div *ngFor="let subtask of task.subtasks; let i = index">
      Subtask: <input [(ngModel)]="task.subtasks[i]">

   </div>
 </div>

{{ tasks | json }}
```